# Import error when using remote Azure Automated Machine Learning model in Azure notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I have trained an automated machine learning model on an Azure ML compute cluster.

I am trying to use that remote model in my Azure hosted Jupyter notebook.

This is the code in the workbook that tries to load the remote model:

```
remote_run = AutoMLRun(experiment = experiment, run_id = '... Experiment id ...')
remote_best_run, remote_fitted_model = remote_run.get_output()
```

This code fails with the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 # remote_run.wait_for_completion(show_output = True)
>         3 import pandas as pd
>   ----> 4 remote_best_run, remote_fitted_model = remote_run.get_output()
>         5 #!pip list
>
> ~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/train/automl/run.py
>   in get_output(self, iteration, metric)
>       406 
>       407         with open(model_local, "rb") as model_file:
>   --> 408             fitted_model = pickle.load(model_file)
>       409         return curr_run, fitted_model
>       410
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps'

Presumably there is a version difference between what is installed on the Azure ML compute cluster vs what is installed in the kernel of the Jupyter notebook, or I have a package missing.

How can I make this remote model work?

For additional reference, I am following this tutorial: https://notebooks.azure.com/NileshA/projects/GlobalAI

**Note 1** I can also reproduce this error by running the following code in my jupyter notebook:

```
import pickle

with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as p_f:
    data = pickle.load(p_f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the Auto ML helpdesk and they solved the problem.

Quote from them:

> We have a bug where the AutoML inferencing fails because the pandas
>   version is 0.22.0 which doesn’t have some API support.

I upgraded pandas on my hosted notebook to version 0.23.4, and after this the model unpickles and works successfully